# Does it make sense to say 寝行きます?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

For example, 眠くてたまらない、僕は今寝行きます。is this acceptable in Japanese?

Comment: Why not 「とても疲れたので寝る」 ? 寝行く seems to make little sense and appears as a literal translation of "go to sleep."

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's my translation after studying some Japanese word construction patterns.  So, Japanese people will never say 寝行く？

Comment: I am not a native, so take the following with a grain of salt: No. It makes little to no sense to sleep and go somewhere with the really close frames of time implied by using masu-stem as a continuative form. Besides this technical aspect, I have never seen 寝行く in any writing, and my IME does not even recognize ねいく as anything more than gibberish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others told you 寝に行きます is the correct structure (the normal masu for the verb, without “masu”, plus に and any verb of motion like 行く 来る 帰る 戻る etc)
It’s commonly used in Japan, I’ve listened to it and I use it commonly.

Answer (score 4):

「寝行{ねい}く」 makes no sense.

「寝{ね}に行{い}く」, however, makes perfect sense and it means "to go to bed".

Comment: Cool. Does 寝に行く sound natural to Japanese? Thanks.